# Firebase send push notifications via curl command works, but not from firebase console

Tags: firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I am developing an app with swift and try integrating push notifications.

Firebase send push notifications via curl command works, but not from firebase console.

I followed every step from different tutorials, used the AuthKey, the bundle ID is correct and i do not receive any errors and the status of the push notification is "done/finished".

Here is the curl command i am using

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: key="My Server Key"
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
-d '{"notification": {"body": "Hellof!", "sound": "default"},
"priority": "high",
"to": "FMC push token"}'
```

I hope someone has a solution for that problem or similar experience.

Comment: What does it say on the Firebase console?

Comment: firebase does not say anything. The push message is finished and the status is "Completed". No errors or anything. Like is said, it does work with curl a command.

Comment: I am facing same issues. Push works from CURL but not working from Firebase console. Not working for both android and iOS. :(

Answer (score 0):

I too got it working in curl using a similar JSON structure as given by you. But in some cases it was resulting in null values for the body and title (I used the title field also)

It became better when I used "data" instead of "notification" in the JSON

Try changing the JSON as shown below. I have not tried it out myself in the exact context that you describe (Firebase console) but when I did that using CURL I found that both body and title are correctly being displayed in the notification

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: key="My Server Key"
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
-d '{"data": {"title": "The Title","body": "Hellof!", "sound": "default"},
"priority": "high",
"to": "FMC push token"}'
```